# Conditions under which the preimage of a submanifold in nontrivial in homology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences, fibre-bundles, homology

Let $\pi: M^{n+k} \to N^n$ be a fibre bundle with fibre $F$ between compact smooth manifolds. What are “mild” sufficient conditions on the topology of $M$, $N$ and $F$ so that given a closed $p$-submanifold $\Sigma^p \subset N$ which is nontrivial in $H_p(N; \mathbb{Z})$, the preimage $\pi^{-1}(\Sigma)$ is nontrivial in $H_{p+k}(M;\mathbb{Z})$? I guess spectral sequences may help, but I am not familiar with them.

Comment: Say $M,N$ and $F$ are oriented without boundary. Then the map $\pi^{-1}: H_p(N,\mathbb Q) \to H_{p+k}(M,\mathbb Q)$ is dual (via Poincaré duality on $M$ and $N$) to the map $\pi_*: H_{n-p}(M,\mathbb Q)\to H_{n-p}(N,\mathbb Q)$. So the former is injective if and only if the latter is surjective.

Comment: @ThomasRot $S^p$ is any closed submanifold of dimension $p$.

Comment: I am skeptical about Nicolas's comment: in the Hopf fibration $S^1 \to S^3 \to S^2$, the map $\pi^{-1}$ as defined in the question is injective, but $\pi_{\ast}$ is clearly not surjective in degree 2.

Comment: As a name for an arbitrary manifold, $S^p$ is probably not ideal...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A sufficient condition with $\mathbf{Q}$ coefficients should be that the fiber $F$ has non-vanising Euler characteristic.

Consider the Gysin map (aka as fiber integraion) $$\pi^{!} = \int_{\pi}\colon H^{\ast}(M;\mathbf{Q}) \to H^{\ast-k}(N;\mathbf{Q});$$ then $\langle \alpha , \pi^{-1}[S]\rangle = \langle \pi^{!} \alpha, [S]\rangle$ for $\alpha \in H^{p+k}(M)$.

So if we can ensure that the RHS is non-zero, it follows that $\pi^{-1}[S] \neq 0$.

But this is the case if $\chi(M) \neq 0$ as with $T_{\pi}$ the vertical tangent bundle of $\pi$, the fact that $\pi^{!}$ is a $\text{H}^{\ast}(N)$-module homomorphism implies that $$\pi^!(e(T_{\pi})\pi^{\ast}(\alpha)) = \pi^!(e(T_{\pi}))\alpha = \chi(F)\alpha,$$
so $\pi^!$ is (rationally) surjective in this case.

Comment: I guess it is not ideal to call $M$ the fiber. It is te total space of the fibre bundle.

Comment: Also, isn’t the Gysim map defined only for sphere bundles?

Comment: Ah, I wrote $M$ two times when in fact I meant $F$ (the fiber), right. I have now corrected that. Fiber integraion is possible not only for sphere bundles. One place where this is used to construct the generalized Miller--Moria--Mumford classes is section 3.1 of this survey I highly recommend: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.08151.pdf

Comment: I see. One more thing: where do I find the definition of Euler class for arbitrary fibre bundles of smooth manifolds?

Comment: It is the usual Euler class (of vector bundles), taken of the vertical tangent bundle $T_{\pi}$ (which is a vector bundle) of the manifold bundle. One way to deal with it in practice is to see the universal smooth $F$-bundle as $F \to B\text{Diff}(F,\ast) \to B\text{Diff}(F)$, then the map $B\text{Diff}(F,\ast) \to BSO(k)$ induced from the differential classifies $T_{\pi_{\text{univ}}}$

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by Nicolas Tholozan in the comments, the map $\pi^{-1}:H_p(N)\to H_{p+k}(M)$ which sends $[S\subset N]$ to $[\pi^{-1}(S)\subset M]$ is Poincaré dual to the map $\pi^*:H^{n-p}(N)\to H^{n-p}(M)$ induced by $\pi$ on cohomology. (Here I'm assuming $M$ and $N$ are both oriented and using integral coefficients.)

So you're really asking for conditions under which the induced map in cohomology is injective. One easy example is when $\pi$ admits a section $\sigma:N\to M$, in which case $\operatorname{Id}_{H^*(N)}=(\pi\circ \sigma)^*=\sigma^*\pi^*$.

Comment: Is the map $\pi^{-1}$ well defined? Not every homology class is representable by submanifolds.

Comment: @EduardoLonga: You're right, I guess what I wrote is a bit misleading. There is a well-defined Gysin homomoprhism $\pi_!:H_p(N)\to H_{p+k}(M)$ which sends the homology class represented by an embedded submanfold to the homology class represented by its pre-image.